# rsync: files copied with hidden attribute

Tags: rsync

I run a backup from Windows 7 machine to Mac machine running Mountain Lion using rsync that is packaged in DeltaCopy application. I can't use DeltaCopy interface because the destination is a mapped drive (Mac's samba drive).

So here is my setup: I have a folder in Mac that is the destination folder and I share this folder via Samba share. On windows machine, I map this samba share to a drive (let's say M:/)

I run rsync:

```
rsync -arv --delete "/cygdrive/C//origin/" "/cygdrive/M//mybackup/"
```

it runs fine except that all files on the destination are hidden. Anyone has an idea on what's happening here? I really appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**RSYNC** does create a temp file, by default in the target directory and named `.<FILE_NAME>.<RANDOM_STRING>`. After copy file has renamed to original name.

After created file with `.` at the beginning of name, OS add HIDDEN-attribute for them. Then **RSYNC** renamed it , but HIDDEN-attribute saved.

To disable temporary-file creation use `--inplace` parameter for **rsync**

Comment: And if the files are already copied, you need to delete them and start a new rsync

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember a bug in afp, I switched the target machines sharing type from AFP to SMB and it solved this issue.